# Python 3 len() method returning wrong number of objects in Tensorflow detection

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, object-detection

With the code below I am running a TensorFlow object detection inference on the images in a directory. The code works fine, except for when I am trying to print the number of objects that are detected in each image.

```
path = '/home/user/Downloads/test/'

for image_path in os.listdir(path):
  input_path = os.path.join(path, image_path)
  print('Evaluating:', input_path)
  image = Image.open(input_path)
  img_width, img_height = image.size
  image_np = np.array(image.getdata()).reshape((img_height, img_width, 3)).astype(np.int32)
  # Run inference.
  start = time.time()
  output_dict = run_inference(detection_graph, image_np)  
  end = time.time()
  # Visualization of the results of a detection.
  vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
      image_np,
      output_dict['detection_boxes'],
      output_dict['detection_classes'],
      output_dict['detection_scores'],
      category_index,
      use_normalized_coordinates=True,
      line_thickness=8)
  plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
  plt.imshow(image_np)
  print("Prediction time for: " + image_path + " " + str(end-start))
  print("Found %d objects." % len(output_dict["detection_scores"]))
```

For some reason that I am not understanding, it always prints that 100 objects are found, even when clearly in the image there are less than 100 objects to detect.

Here is an example:

```
Evaluating: /home/user/Downloads/test/P2044.png
Prediction time for: P2044.png 4.666229724884033
Found 100 objects.

Evaluating: /home/user/Downloads/test/P1854.jpg
Prediction time for: P1854.jpg 4.627516984939575
Found 100 objects.
```

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try to set `max_boxes_to_draw=100` and `min_score_thresh` to some lower value (default is 0.5) in function `visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array`. Then you should be able to get desired output.

Comment: Thank you, I Just tried, but it still doesn't work.